# Рейтинг полностью зависящий от количества поделившихся в соц.сетях возможно ли?

Tags: php, javascript

Здравствуйте.

У меня есть сайт каталог радиостанций с рейтингом, но его постоянно накручивают и вообще толку от него не много.

Возникла идея сделать рейтинг полностью зависящий от количества поделившихся в соц.сетях реально ли сделать? Может знаете уже где-то реализовано?

Answer (score 1):

Так себе идея

1) счетчики соц сетей можно крутить вобще без проблем, будут крутить как ваши рейтинги

2) счетчики подлившихся не вечные, находятся на левых сайтах, от вас не зависят...если что случится вы ничего не сможете исправить, все данные подохнут

Лучше боротся с накруткой ваших рейтингов, вы их хотя бы видете со всех сторон